# Gopro-py-api (KonradIT) - night exposition

Tags: python, long-integer, gopro, exposure

Dear Python programmers here, can someone advises, which command use for a night shot - with long exposure. I suppose something with gpControlSet before goproCamera.take_photo(1) - I have gopro7. Daily photos and video without a problem.
Gopro-py-api (KonradIT) https://github.com/KonradIT/gopro-py-api

````
goproCamera = GoProCamera.GoPro()
goproCamera.overview()

// for me most useful commands

goproCamera.take_photo(1)
goproCamera.downloadLastMedia(goproCamera.take_photo(1))
goproCamera.delete("all")
goproCamera.downloadAll("")
goproCamera.downloadLastMedia(gopro.take_photo(), custom_filename="HDR_"+name+".jpg")
goproCamera.listMedia(True)```
````

Comment: Can you make this question a little more specific, please?  For example, you should include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and provide details of what you've tried and why the result was not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Konrad Iturbe here, you do that like so:

```
gpCam.mode(constants.PhotoMode, constants.SubMode.Photo.Night)
gpCam.shutter(constants.start)
```